# Hide custom column in admin template screen (Elementor)

Tags: custom-field, columns, screen-columns

My plugin adds a custom column to admin posts and pages screens but it's also adding it to the Templates (Elementor) screen. I know users can hide this themselves, but I'd rather do it in my plugin.

The page where I want to remove the column is:
edit.php?post_type=elementor_library&tabs_group=library&mode=list

The custom column was added using this code:

```
add_filter('manage_pages_columns', 'customfield_add_column', 5);
add_action('manage_pages_custom_column', 'customfield_add_column_values', 5, 2);
add_filter('manage_posts_columns', 'customfield_add_column', 5);
add_action('manage_posts_custom_column', 'customfield_add_column_values', 5, 2);

function customfield_add_column($defaults){
    // field vs displayed title
    $defaults['my_custom_field'] = __('MyField');
    return $defaults;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the second parameter `$post_type` passed to [`manage_posts_columns`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/manage_posts_columns/) and ignore adding the column if it matches `elementor_library`:

```php
add_filter( 'manage_posts_columns', 'customfield_add_column', 5, 2 /* <= Make sure you add the 2 here to pass the second parameter to your callback */ );

function customfield_add_column( $defaults, $post_type = null ) {
    if ( $post_type !== 'elementor_library' ) {
        $defaults['my_custom_field'] = __( 'MyField' );
    }

    return $defaults;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! And easy! Thanks!